# Android Room database error Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type in room android

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

Entity class
Here is entity class for room database

I am getting an error while building which says cannot figure out how to convert LiveData<List>

```
@Entity(tableName = "weather_table")
        data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
            @PrimaryKey()
            var id: Int? = 1,
            @TypeConverters(CurrentConverter::class)
            val current: Current?,
            @TypeConverters(DailyConverter::class)
            val daily: List<Daily>?,
            val lat: Double?,
            val lon: Double?
        )



data class Daily(
    val dt: Long?,
    val sunrise: Int?,
    val sunset: Int?,
    @TypeConverters(TempConverter::class)
    val temp: Temp?,
    @TypeConverters(WeatherConverter::class)
    val weather: List<Weather>?,
)
```

Here are type converters

class DailyConverter {

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun dailListyToString(daily: List<Daily>): String {
        return try {
            val type = object: TypeToken<List<Daily>>() {}.type
            Gson().toJson(daily, type)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            return "[]"
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToDailyList(value: String): List<Daily> {
        return try {
            val type = object: TypeToken<List<Daily>>() {}.type
            Gson().fromJson(value, type)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

@Dao
interface WeatherDao {

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertWeather(currentWeather: CurrentWeatherResponse): Long

@Query("DELETE from weather_table")
suspend fun deleteAllData()

@Query("SELECT * FROM weather_table")
fun getAllDailyWeather(): MutableLiveData<List<CurrentWeatherResponse>>

@Query("SELECT daily FROM weather_table WHERE id = 1")
fun getListOfDaily(): MutableLiveData<List<Daily>>
```

}

Inside Viewmodel I get it with this method

```
  fun getAllWeather() = database.getAllDailyWeather()
```

Comment: Please format your codes for better readability.

Comment: What is wrong here? I think everything is formatted correctly and by the way I solved it already

Comment: https://imgur.com/MKI5EeZ... and if you solved the problem, please add the solution to your qustion